# Unrecognized Selector - [NSView borderRect]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm having trouble getting the NSRect of a view's border.  I keep getting an unrecognized selector error.

Here is the code:

```
NSGradient *BorderGradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor blackColor] endingColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
[BorderGradient drawInRect:[self.window.contentView borderRect] angle:-90];
// Unrecognized Selector error here
```

I'm trying to access the border rect to add a color gradient to the border.  The code also crashes when I try to access the borderRect by itself, like this:

```
NSRect rect = [self.window.contentView borderRect];
NSLog(@"origin.x = %f", rect.origin.x);
```

And if trying to convert the drawInRect: to CGRect.  Like so:

```
NSGradient *BorderGradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor blackColor] endingColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
[BorderGradient drawInRect:NSRectToCGRect([self.window.contentView borderRect]) angle:-90];
// Unrecognized Selector error here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSView` doesn't have a method named `-borderRect`. Is it a custom method you've implemented? `NSBox` does have a `-borderRect` method. Are you expecting your window's content view to be an instance of NSBox? Have you checked to see that that's actually true.

Perhaps you really want `-frame` or `-bounds`?

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful.  So it is not a custom method that I've implemented, but it still comes up as valid.  I found that my window's content view is not an instance of NSBox, but I still don't want -frame or -bounds.  I want to get the NSRect of the view's border and be able to add a gradient to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should create a custom subclass of NSView. In your subclass, draw a border using a gradient (override `-drawRect:`). Then, make your window's content view an instance of your custom subclass (you can set this up in Interface Builder, or if creating the window programmatically using `-[NSWindow setContentView:]`).

For what it's worth, `-frame` and `-bounds` both return an NSRect that is in fact the rectangle that defines the view's border. In your custom `-drawRect:` method, you'll have to use `-bounds` to get the rectangle to draw.

Comment: Great advice, which would work great, but this will still create a gradient over the entire bounds of the view.  I am still looking for a way to add a gradient over just the border (think thin, colored, gradient border around just the edge of the view) of the view - not the entire view.  Do you know of any way to do that?

Comment: I left the particulars up to you :). Take a look at `-[NSGradient drawInBezierPath:angle:]`, etc. If you need more details, you should ask a new question (link to it here, if you'd like), because this question is specifically about a unrecognized selector error, not how to draw a gradient in a border.

Answer (score 1):

`NSView` (what is returned from `self.window.contentView`) does not have a `borderRect` method, which is causing the *Unrecognized Selector error*.

You probably want `frame` or `bounds` instead.